# Why does angular velocity changes as i strech my hands?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, angular-velocity

Suppose I am sitting on a turnable chair. I have given that turnable chair some angular velocity $\omega$ and it starts rotating around me as axis of rotation.

Now at that instant suppose I expand out my hands with some weight on both sides.Now, It's mentioned in my book that the angular velocity decreases!! i.e $\omega'\lt \omega$.

Again as I brings my hands closer my angular velocity is restored.

I was wondering what's the possible reason behind this?

**My question:-**
Why the angular velocity decreases with expansion of my hands and why its restored again?

Moreover what is the role of conservation of angular momentum in this case and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your angular velocity changes depending on your arms' extension due to [conservation of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Conservation_of_angular_momentum).

Conservation of angular momentum implies that the quantity
$$\bf \vec L=I{\bf\vec\omega}={\text{constant}}$$ This means in a rotating system changing from some state $1$ to another $2$ then $$\bf I_1\omega_1=I_2\omega_2=\text{constant}$$

Applying this to your situation, if your moment of inertia (see [image of figure skater here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Definition))  is initially $I_1$ when your hands are closer together, and you also have angular velocity $\bf\omega_1$ then when you extend your hands you have a new moment of inertia $I_2$ where$^1$ $I_2\gt I_1$ and so from the above equation $\bf\omega_1\gt\omega_2$ where $\bf\omega_2$ is your new angular velocity.

So your angular velocity is smaller when you extend your arms, and higher when you bring them closer so that angular momentum stays the same.

`Moreover what is the role of conservation of angular momentum in this case and how?`

Conservation of angular momentum is playing
a *fundamental* role here as explained above.

$^1$ [Moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) is larger when more mass is distributed further from the axis of rotation.

Comment: Well still I don't see why angular momentum is constant before and after expanding the hands? The other parts of the answer is well written except this one..

Comment: Can you be more specific? Angular momentum conservation is a law of nature and arises from rotational symmetry. Changing $I$ will change $\bf\omega$ such that the product of $I\bf\omega$ is always the same. I'm not really sure what it is that you're not understanding. Let me know.

Comment: If the angular momentum is conserved, it means that net torque is zero right? Why is net torque zero in this case?

Comment: There are no external torques operating on you, are there (ignoring friction)? If there was, like a friend grabbing your arm, this is an external torque and will decrease $\omega$ so that angular momentum will not be conserved.

Comment: so no external forces(ignoring the friction) are being acted and hence external torque doesn't exist right?

Comment: Exactly right Rahul. Meaning angular momentum is conserved.